# How is Goswami's stand on nationalism distinct from Andersons'?

Tags: historiography, nationalism, indian

Benedict Anderson in his '[Imagined Communities](https://archive.org/details/ImaginedCommunitiesReflectionsOnTheOriginAndSpreadOfNationalismNewEdition/page/n1)' argued that nationalism is modular, that is transplanted to the third world without acknowledging the agency of the intellectual elite, by simply defining the process of origin of nationalism to be passive reception by bilingual elite, who had at their disposal both western model as well of their own.

Partha Chatterjee criticized Benedict Anderson's work by showing Indian nationalism was divided into political nationalism which is outer domain where colonizers are superior while inner domain where colonized are dominant.

But Manu Goswami had problems with work of Benedict Anderson as well as Partha Chatterjee.

So my problem is how Manu Goswami's stand on Nationalism is different from Benedict Anderson. What does Manu Goswami mean by '*Socio-historical Conception of Nationalism*'?

---

[Rethinking the Modular Nation Form: Toward a Sociohistorical Conception of Nationalism](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3879522?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) by Manu Goswami

[The Nation and its Fragments: Colonial and Postcolonial Histories](https://press.princeton.edu/titles/5286.html) - by Partha Chatterjee

Comment: Is this question about history? I'm seeing a lot of present tense in it.

Comment: @T.E.D. As written, I suspect that it is more about political science than history.